# VLAN creation with trunk port configuration

Tags: cisco, switch, vlan, cisco-catalyst, trunk

I have three switches and I configured VLAN with trunk on those switches but my requirement is VLAN 1, VLAN 2, VLAN 3 has to be configured on Switch 1 and Switch 3, but I don't need VLAN 2 configuration on Switch 2, so for this requirement for configuration, what should I have to configure and in which switch?

```
Switch 1 <---> Switch 2 <---> Switch 3
VLAN 1-3       VLAN 1,3       VLAN 1-3
```

Comment: You question is confusing. Do you mean that Switch 1 needs all three VLANs, but Switch 2 needs only VLANs 1 and 3? Also, what are the switch models?

Comment: Yes, three switches are connected and switch model cisco catalyst 2960 model and for example first and third switches need vlan 1 ,2,3 access but in second switch only need vlan 1& 3 access only.

Comment: But how are they connected (star, bus, ring)? Which interfaces are connected to which switches?

Comment: which is connected in Bus topology

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to configure the switch interfaces as trunks:

```
switchport mode trunk
```

You may want to restrict the VLANs on the trunks:

```
switchport trunk allowed vlan 1 - 3
```

All three VLANs will be transported across the trunks, but you simply do not use VLAN 2 on any Switch 2 access interfaces.

A better design is to use a star topology, where both Switch 2 and Switch 3 connect back to Switch 1. You can then restrict the trunk interfaces between Switch 1 and Switch 2 to VLANs 1 and 3:

```
switchport trunk allowed vlan 1 , 3
```

If you connect them in a ring, you could also use the above command for the trunk interfaces between Switch 2 and Switch 3.